# SQL Multi-Function Variable

Tags: sql, variables, reference

I have a fairly long bit of SQL code that creates a number of temp tables.  Within the different creations there are some functions that occur multiple times.  The functions are constant but they have an int at the end to change the result range, eg.

`WHERE getdate() between mfg_ww_begin_datetime and mfg_ww_end_datetime) -2`

When I want to change my overall query, I have to go in and manually change each of these ints - is there a way to set these ints at the top of my query so that I can change just one value and each time it is used in the rest, it references that value I have control of at the top?

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not the smartest, but this works after some more searching.

```
DECLARE @CurrentWW INT, @SampleSize INT, @RollingAvg INT
SET @CurrentWW = 7
SET @SampleSize = 25
SET @RollingAvg = 10
```

And using those variable names in the rest of the query.  They can be referenced multiple times.